# How to rewrite subdomain to path containing subdomain name with mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Using mod_rewrite, 
How would I redirect:

```
http://subdomain.noorderlijn.be/files/file.jpg
```

to:

```
http://www.noorderlijn.be/files/subdomain/file.jpg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this to the `.htaccess` file in the web document root folder (often `public_html` or `htdocs`) of `subdomain`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} subdomain.noorderlijn.be
RewriteRule ^files/(.*) http://www.noorderlijn.be/files/subdomain/$1 [NE,R,L]
```

Once you are satisfied that the redirect works, you can change the `R` to `R=301` to make it permanent.
This assumes that mod_rewrite is **both** installed **and** activated for htaccess files. 
If you are not sure, to check if mod_rewrite is installed, look at the list of installed modules in the output of `phpinfo();`
By default, mod_rewrite is not enabled for htaccess files. If you are managing your own server, open `httpd.conf`
and make sure that the webroot directory block contains one of these lines: `AllowOverride FileInfo` or `AllowOverride All`